# Is it possible to use a plugin built for DM2 in DM3?

Tags: sdk, version, dm-script

is there a workaround to use a plugin built for DM2 in Digital Micrograph 3 without recompile it in DM3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Plugins are compiled DLLs and need to be linked accordingly.

(I assume you are referring to C++ code compiled .dll plugins using the SDK, not script-packages.)

Comment: Yes I mean that. Thanks for your answer! Then I need to ask for source code and try to recompile it.

Comment: @TaiminYang Yes. The SDK for GMS 2 and GMS 3 is very similar, but not identical. You might need to adapt a bit, depending on what the plugin did. Mostly, if it interacted with the UI.